# when I update Mysql, show updated data in page without refresh or click

Tags: java, mysql

i.e; if there is update in wallet balance if any transaction is done then latest balance is updated in MYSQL, also i have web dashboard for the same too. What i need is that, i want latest updated balance to automatically get changed in dashboard without any page event if user is already on that page.

i can do it through AJAX call on regular interval, but this will create huge load on server as there will be large no of request sent on the server to fetch the data.

Any suggestion will be helpful.....please respond.

Comment: You can add one thread which checks for the update in db after some time and update the dashboard.

Comment: use websocket, sse or server push events.

Comment: @Lokesh can u explain bit? , i think as per ur sggestion that will also create load on server for every thread request....is it that way?

Comment: You can implement one thread which runs after some time and then sleeps for some time after execution.

Comment: @mrmcwolf i am fresher....so can u share some piece of code for that or any reference example?

Comment: right....but that will send request to server according to thread sleep time, and data will updated as per request, that will send request on server every time thread wakes up.

Comment: but i want that thread to wake up only when there is update in value in MYSQL table for that user.......if it is possible that will reduce the load on server.....that is what is needed....to reduce server load to minimum possible.

Comment: You can go for websocket then

Comment: can u provide me reference example or any piece of code for that....i am fresher so need a little help further..

Comment: start by reading a wikipedia page and look for the tutorials. you will find plenty